# Hibernate @OneToMany removing from Set doesn't trigger constraint validation on update of parent entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, bean-validation

I have the following scenario:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups_supervisors")

public class SupervisorEntity extends AbstractEntity {
  
  @ManyToOne
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
  KibanaAdGroupEntity kibanaAdGroup;
  
   //Another fields

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
      return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
      return false;

    SupervisorEntity that = (SupervisorEntity) o;

    if (!Objects.equals(id, that.id))
      return false;
    if (kibanaAdGroup!=null && !kibanaAdGroup.getId().equals(that.kibanaAdGroup.getId()))
      return false;
    if (!Objects.equals(name, that.name))
      return false;
    if (!Objects.equals(updateDate, that.updateDate))
      return false;
    return Objects.equals(dateAdd, that.dateAdd);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = id.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + (kibanaAdGroup != null ? kibanaAdGroup.getId().hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + updateDate.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + dateAdd.hashCode();
    return result;
  }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "ad_groups")
public class KibanaAdGroupEntity extends AbstractEntity {
     
  @NotNull 
  @Size(min = 2)
  @BatchSize(size = 10)
  @ToString.Exclude
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "kibanaAdGroup", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval =true)
  Set<SupervisorEntity> supervisors;
  
  //Some other fields
  
  //Destroy releation
  public Set<SupervisorEntity> removeSupervisor(SupervisorEntity supervisor) {
    supervisors.remove(supervisor);
    supervisor.setKibanaAdGroup(null);
    return supervisors;
  }

}
```

When I'm trying to perform following

```
  @Transactional
  public void test() {
    var adGroup = adGroupRepository.findAll().stream().limit(1000).filter(adGr -> adGr.getId() == 142)
      .findFirst().get();
    var supervisor = adGroup.getSupervisors().iterator().next();
    adGroup.removeSupervisor(supervisor);
    adGroupRepository.save(adGroup);
  }
```

expected that `adGroupRepository.save(adGroup)` will  perform update cascade on `adGroup` and constraint `@Size(min = 2)` on `Set<SupervisorEntity> supervisors` will trigger an exception.
I tried to debug `DefaultFlushEntityEventListener::dirtyCheck` , but I see that an old entity and new one one contain identical size of `supervisors`
Please can any one clarify to me where I've mistaken and how to trigger update/checking of this constraint?

UPD
In logs and DB I see that supervisor was successfully deleted

```
2022-10-23 10:37:07.022 DEBUG [4b5430e5fcb074b6,4b5430e5fcb074b6] 93041 - [8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                : \n     delete \n     from\n         public.groups_supervisors \n     where\n         id=? 
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        public.groups_supervisors 
    where
        id=?
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `saveAndFlush` in your test instead? Also, double check if the size of the set actually changes after the call to `supervisors.remove` - could be a `hashCode/equals` issue

Comment: @crizzis Thank you for answer, but it doesn't work for me. I tried it with `saveAndFlush` and also checked `hashCode` of `agGroup` reference before and after invocation of `removeSupervisor` method, they were different(also checked `equals` by copying entity before modification to newly created object, result is false)

Answer (score 0):

For the lazy loaded association mapping , it is suggested to place the validation annotations on the getter rather on the field because of the following reasons mentioned from the [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=8.0#validator-checkconstraints-orm) :

> When lazy loaded associations are supposed to be validated it is
> recommended to place the constraint on the getter of the association.
> Hibernate ORM replaces lazy loaded associations with proxy instances
> which get initialized/loaded when requested via the getter. If, in
> such a case, the constraint is placed on field level, the actual proxy
> instance is used which will lead to validation errors.

So please try :

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "ad_groups")
public class KibanaAdGroupEntity extends AbstractEntity {

  
  @BatchSize(size = 10)
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "kibanaAdGroup", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval =true)
  Set<SupervisorEntity> supervisors;

   @NotNull 
   @Size(min = 2)
   Set<SupervisorEntity> getSupervisors(){
      return this.supervisors;
   }

}
```

Comment: Hello! I tried it, but it tool no affect. Tried a random switch between EAGER and LAZY

Comment: try to make the getter to be public ?

Comment: I've initially made it public)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I found the problem. This happens due to what type hibernate will inject into `Set` field. When you perform `findAll` - `Set` field will be injected as `PersistenSet` type by default. This is shared reference between yours business logic side and `dirty check mechanism` of hibernate. So when you

```
adGroup.removeSupervisor(supervisor);
adGroupRepository.save(adGroup);
```

That operation triggers `DefaultFlushEntityEventListener::dirtyCheck`. But due to `final Object[] loadedState = entry.getLoadedState();` keeps `shared reference`, for hibernate it looks like entity wasn't  change state of the entity. That's why no validation error was occurred(but child entity will be deleted as expected by orphan removal)
PS
If you will change any field of the entity validation will be performed as expected